# DirectX Window & Windows Basic Causes Drawing Artifacts

Tags: winapi, directx

I have an app that creates 1 or more windows. These windows are Direct3D contexts, in which I do rendering.

When Windows has hardware acceleration turned on for the desktop (Aero), everything renders fine. I can move the window around without issue.

If I switch the Windows theme to Windows Basic, it's a disaster. The window renders properly, but if I drag the window around, it leaves a trail of the image behind it. Think of winning at Solitaire.

Any ideas what might be causing this. It's fine otherwise, but it seems to just draw all over everything as it's moved around.

The DirectX renderer is very simple. Clear, Select Texture, Select Vertex Buffer, Select Index Buffer, Draw.

**Update**

The window hierarchy for each window is as follows:

Parent Window, `WS_EX_LAYERED` and `WS_POPUP`. GDI+ draws a frame around the window.
Child Window, `WS_EX_TOOLCHAIN` and `WS_POPUP | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN`. DirectX draws into the child.

Comment: Are the D3D contexts child windows or top-level windows?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've determined, if you aren't in a compositing mode, moving a DirectX window will do this. A lot of examples have the rendering code in the main loop, which means the PeakMessage hangs the renderer.

The solution is, before any MoveWindow call, detect whether compositing is enabled, via system version checking and DwmIsCompositionEnabled. If we can't composite, snapshot the rendered window, hide the DirectX window and draw the snapshot. Once movement is done, turn rendering back on.